# Using Firebase without duplicating business logic

Tags: firebase, business-logic

We have a simple scenario with a web app and a mobile app. Both apps consume a server side web API. Our business logic resides only on that API.

We are migrating from AWS RDS to Firebase. I see everywhere I don't need to use server side code with Firebase, but how can I access Firebase directly from my app (mobile and web) without duplicating my business logic on both applications?

I understand that this approach (use just Firebase without server side code) is for simple apps. But almost every app I can think of must have a server side API, if I don't want to replicate my logic.

Am I missing something or do I really have to have a server side API still?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is "why?", why do you think you need a server side api? Your question is too broad otherwise. As always, almost everything goes case by base; most of the time you'll do fine by doing all the work on the client and leaving security to the database (very important to learn how to write good security rules), and almost always in any big project you'll need a few functions running on the server to avoid exposing private keys or running code you cannot possibly execute on the client (but this is the exception, not the rule).

Comment: I agree with you. But let me give ou some context. Lets say everytime I add a new Product an email must be sent. I have to write that rule on both applications (web end mobile)? Lets imagine my logic changes... Do I need to *remember* everywhere I put that logic? Using an API I would have to update just one place. Now imagine the scenario where I have a web app, ios app, wp app and Android app. I would have to update my code everywhere. Its not that hard to imagine that something will be missed.

Comment: Oh right, I've been working with cross-platform javascript for so long that I forgot about those issues XD. Yeah in that case I guess you have to keep working in the same fashion. Still think it'd be more useful if you posted a more specific question about a real scenario, if you want to get more insight an ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Since both my apps are javascript apps (ionic and angular) I will create javascript modules and share between them.

Source:
https://medium.com/@benorama/hybrid-mobile-apps-sharing-logic-between-angular2-and-ionic2-apps-7c32145b90d5#.trt4lpc8a

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a write-once-run-anywhere solution.You can look at:

- web-based solutions (e.g. progressive web apps)
- hybrid solutions (e.g. Ionic)
- near-native solutions (e.g. React Native, NativeScript)
- cross-compiling solutions (eg. Intel XDK)

...and probably a few other categories.

If none of those suit your needs, you will have to:

- embed the logic in Firebase security rules and/or
- write an intermediary or auxiliary server (see this [article on application architectures](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html)) and/or
- duplicate logic into apps written in the native technology of iOS and Android

Comment: Actually we use Ionic for our mobile version and angular2 for our web version. I said iOS, Android, wp just to illustrate. The simple question is: is it better to use replicate my business logic on both apps (web and Ionic) or to use a web api as middleware between the apps and Firebase and keep the logic in just one place?